# Keep financial data even when removing user from data base

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a system that manages clubs and associations.

> One key factor of this system is that one person can be a member of more than one club.

Right now I'm facing an issue where my system is loosing financial records references when one user is longer a member of an association. To visualize it a little better I made a simplified version of the tables related to finances.

[image]

So basically I have one table that has the associations, one that has each group of associates, so the associate would be the identification for the family and then the members, that would be the dad, mom, son, etc... Each associate needs to have one and just one responsible, who would receive all the comunication, manage the associate certificate, pay the bills.

All the associations work on a monthly subscription, paide by the member responsible and it can also have others expenses, such as restaurants, rental of barbecue areas, party room, etc.

These finances are stored in the `tb_finance` table, which references the `tb_associate`. This is where my problem is today.

If one family decides they no longer wants to be part of the association, or (I think it's worse), they decide to sell their Certificate to another family, the finances will break.

I'm not loosing all info, but I'll loose the link between them. `tb_associate` and `tb_user` will never have their info deleted. But `tb_associate_member` will.

---

I thought about creating another table to create a direct reference with the users and finances, for example, like this:

[image]

This way `tb_associate_finance` will never be deleted, thus keeping its users reference.

I just don't feel like this is the best way to solve this problem. It seems to have a better and simple way to achieve this result.

> For each member responsible, it's possible that they have an apiKey used by an external third party system integrated (similar to paypal) to generate the bills for credit card, etc, to be paid.

Comment: What is `associate`.`name`?  It seems irrelevant.  Or maybe redundant.

Comment: @RickJames it's a reference the associations uses to identify the associates easier. It's usually the family last name, but some have other names

Answer (score 0):

I see two entities:  `Users` and `Associations`

I see one complex many-to-many relationship between those two entities.

See if you can lay out the data using only those 3 tables.

While you are at it, get rid of `id` in the many-to-many relation table.  And have just these two indexes:

```
 PRIMARY KEY(user_id, assoc_id),
 INDEX(assoc_id, user_id)
```

Comment: On which table? Is it following the second image I proposed?

Comment: You have 5 (first image) and 6 (second image) tables; I am asking whether the schema will fit in just 3 tables.

Comment: It's hard, because there are other areas of the system that uses them. Some need the reference of the `tb_associate_member`. And I use the `tb_user` on a different table because one user can be member of more than one `tb_association` at once, this is why I have the `tb_associate_member`.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade - OK.